# ARM linux kernel head-common.S

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

I was looking head-common.S

at the __mmap_switched:

```
.long   init_thread_union + THREAD_START_SP @ sp //for stack pointer
```

THREAD_START_SP is defined THREAD_SIZE(8192) - 8 in "thread+info.h"

set stack size 8KB(8129) and minus 8byte.

why minus 8byte?

i suspect, i think DA(decrement after) right?

Comment: Rather, Decrement Before (Fully Descending - FD) - the ARM `push` / `pop` mnemonics are implemented as `stmfd sp!, ...` and `ldmfd sp!, ...` so it's decrement-before on pushes, increment-after on pops. But since words on ARM are only four bytes, that difference wouldn't explain why it keeps eight in reserve. My guess is an initial `fp`/`lr` pair, but would need to look up the eABI to validate that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25244273/1163019

Comment: possible duplicate of [In ARM Linux, what is the purpose of the few bytes reserved at the "bottom" of kernel stack for each thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237607/in-arm-linux-what-is-the-purpose-of-the-few-bytes-reserved-at-the-bottom-of-k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 8 bytes aligned is the requirement in APCS.

In APCS, the chapter 5.2.1 The Stack,

The stack must also conform to the following constraint at a public interface:

**SP mod 8 = 0. The stack must be double-word aligned.**

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the "why" at all. If subtracting 8 leaves it 8-byte aligned, it was _already 8-byte aligned_ beforehand.