# In ARM Linux, what is the purpose of the few bytes reserved at the "bottom" of kernel stack for each thread

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm

**Question**:

Why are 8 bytes reserved at the "bottom" of kernel stack when it is created?

**Background**:

We know that `struct pt_regs` and `thread_info` share the same 2 consecutive pages(8192 bytes), with `pt_reg` located at the higher end and `thread_info` at the lower end.
However, I noticed that 8 bytes are reserved at the highest address of these 2 pages:

in arch/arm/include/asm/threadinfo.h

```
#define THREAD_START_SP     (THREAD_SIZE - 8)
```

Comment: Loaded at thread creation with a 'return' address that points at 'TerminateThread()' ??

Comment: fork() is often used to create a new thread, but fork() return either 0(for child thread) or pid of its child(for parent thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are 8 bytes reserved at the "bottom" of kernel stack when it is created?

1. If we reserve anything on the stack, it must be a multiple of eight.
2. If we peek above the stack, we like to make sure it is mapped.

### Multiple of eight

The stack and user register needs to be aligned to 8 bytes.  This just makes things more efficient as many ARMs have a 64bit bus and operations on the kernel stack (such as `ldrd` and `strd`) may have these requirements.  You can see [the protection in `usr_entry` macro](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S#n307).  Specifically,

```
#if defined(CONFIG_AEABI) && (__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__ >= 5) && (S_FRAME_SIZE & 7)
#error "sizeof(struct pt_regs) must be a multiple of 8"
#endif
```

ARMv5 (architecture version 5) adds the `ldrd` and `strd` instructions.  It is also a requirement of the EABI version of the kernel (versus OABI).  So if we reserve anything on the stack, it must be a multiple of 8.

### Peeking on stack

For the very top frame, we may want to take a peek at previous data.  In order not to constantly check that the stack is in the 8K range an extra entry is reserved.  Specifically, I think that signals need to peek at the stack.

Comment: I will try to find where the kernel peeks at the stack, if you are interested.  I vaguely remember reading this some place, but couldn't quickly locate it now.  The [signal.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/signal.c#n189) is definitely looking at the stack, but I remember an explicit comment somewhere and I think it was in assembler.

Comment: First item reads very wrong, second item sounds also wrong since peeking is looking at stack since it is full-descending, it is not peeking above. and what is user register?

Comment: @auselen The first part basically said what is in your original answer *Eight bytes come from the ARM calling convention that SP needs to be 8-byte aligned*.  User registers are stored on the kernel stack; generally `pt_regs`.  During a signal, the current kernel context is interrupted and a signal is returned to the user space; the previous context lives above the signal context.  The kernel does not have to follow an AAPCS; see [entry-armv.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S#n320), empty descend?

Comment: Err; whatever the ARM stack notation is, the `usr_entry` first decrements a full frame, so it does not normally write to the top of the stack.  It seems it would be ok to use `THREAD_SIZE` for normal kernel stack use;  I would not surprise me if this is not the case.  However, the signals do definitely look above the current stack frame.  A key point is to not cause an illegal access out of the stack/thread pages.

Comment: @auselen  I mean the **user registers** stored on the kernel stack need to be 8 byte aligned so that the assembler will work well.  Of course you can not align the physical registers (R0-R12 are shared by modes, so there is no real **user registers**; the copy from user space on the stack).  Sorry, someone not familiar with context switch code might be confuse by that statement.  If I must make an edit, I will clarify.

Comment: that's why I used the words "reads", "sounds" - nothing big. You say "If we reserve anything on the stack, it must be a multiple of eight." and I read it like you can't push an int to stack :) AAPCS (5.2.1) also dictates a full-descending stack, so I believe that's what Linux follow.

Answer (score 6):

This way you can access to `thread_info` structure just by reading stack pointer and masking out `THREAD_SIZE` bits (otherwise `SP` initially would be on the next `THREAD_SIZE` block).

```
static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
{
        register unsigned long sp asm ("sp");
        return (struct thread_info *)(sp & ~(THREAD_SIZE - 1));
}
```

Eight bytes come from the ARM calling convention that `SP` needs to be 8-byte aligned.

**Update:**
[AAPCS](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf) 5.2.1.1 states:

> > A process may only access (for reading or writing) the closed interval of the entire stack delimited by [SP, stack-base – 1] (where SP is the value of register r13).

Since stack is full-descending

```
THREAD_START_SP (THREAD_SIZE - 8)
```

would enforce this requirement probably by illegal access to next page (segmentation fault).