# ARM Linux: How to get current_pt_regs

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm a newbie of Linux, currently I read some code of Linux, and I see a macro current_pt_regs in arch/arm/include/asm/ptrace.h defined as below:

```
#define current_pt_regs(void) ({ (struct pt_regs *)         \
        ((current_stack_pointer | (THREAD_SIZE - 1)) - 7) - 1;  \
})
```

In my opinion `current_stack_pointer | (THREAD_SIZE - 1)` can get the top address of stack. But what confused me is that, why it has -7?

Can someone tell me something about that?

Thanks and regards,

kan.

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/25237607/2189500

Comment: Emm, it seems that's the same question. So I think the reason why here shoud minus 7 is that the sp start 7 bytes after the top of stack. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In ARM Linux, what is the purpose of the few bytes reserved at the "bottom" of kernel stack for each thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237607/in-arm-linux-what-is-the-purpose-of-the-few-bytes-reserved-at-the-bottom-of-k)